# Transformation (square root/log/) of count data that has already been normalised

Tags: data-transformation, normality-assumption, count-data

#### Reproducible example of complex research question....

I am trying to do a simple comparison of three groups called 'red', 'blue' and 'green' based on count data.

How I collect the data involves counting how many 'red', 'blue' and 'green' objects are in an image. I then divide each red count by the total area taken up by red, blue and green objects and call it red density (for normalisation purposes - some images are a lot smaller and hence have smaller counts, so must be normalised to total area). The same goes for green and blue i.e. I then divide each blue count by the total area taken up by red, blue and green objects and call it blue density. etc... The count data has now turned into continuous decimal data.

Normality testing is showing that the data is non-parametric. My question is whether to use a square root transformation or log transformation, before conducting an ANOVA etc...

I know count data usually involves square root transformations, but as I have already 'normalised' to area, would a log be more appropriate?

OR

Is it better to transform (by either method) the counts THEN divide by the total area? I don't think that option makes sense in my head, but unsure what the best steps would be to take.

OR

Should I just treat data as non-parametric and conduct a Kruskal-Wallis without any transformation?

QQplot of data with no transformation: (of example dataset)
[image]

QQplot of data with log transformation:

[image: log transformed]

(No square root QQplot is available at the moment..)

Comment: "Data is non-parametric"; no; methods may be non-parametric. Calling data non-parametric is like confusing illnesses and medical treatments. Otherwise: do you have any data that are zeros? Which transformation works best? Good advice is almost impossible without seeing graphs of raw data, root transformed data, log transformed data. The best graphs are normal quantile plots. No normality test results. thanks: as you have data from images presumably your sample sizes are quite large and normality tests are fairly useless for large samples. (They aren't much use for small samples.)

Comment: My samples have no zeros, and sample size ranges between 5-90 depending on the dataset. So normality testing is required for those smaller datasets.

Comment: Your software seems to be scaling observed values to standardized values. I find plots with original scales far more illuminating. Clearly values are closer to normal (Gaussian) on log scale, but that transformation is also a little strong. I suspect analysis of variance on raw and transformed data will give consistent results. Jumping to Kruskal-Wallis does not seem needed. If normality is relevant at all it needs to be done separately for your three groups.

Comment: Check more general Box-Cox/power transformation: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform